# Raspberry Pi doesn't boot sometimes, turns off sometimes but a few minutes later turns off again

Tags: sd-card, raspbian

Hello I have the following problem, my Raspberry PI 3b+ doesn't start sometimes and when it does start if I do anything (for example remote-desktop through `xrdp` to install an application or just I login with `ssh`) the lights turn the same when it doesn't boot(video below).

I reinstalled Raspbian on an other sd-card but the problem is the same. The led behave always in the same way when the PI doesn't work.  PWR most of the time on, ACT FLICKER a bit then blink 2 times clearly and the flicker again.  Sometimes it repeat this 5 times and then the Raspberry PI work again only I do something.

I tried also different power supplies but that doesn't change anything.
Have anybody the same problem? Can you help me?

Thank you

Edit:
The Gpio-Board is nothing connected, I use wlan, a speaker is connected (the power supply is not connected to the pi just the 3.5mm audio jack), I install and used a apache webserver, I don't connect any keyboard or monitor just shh connection via putty, (I connected once an external hdd but I remove it ), I also checked both sd-cards for damage.

Video: https://anonfile.com/77q8X2Vcm7/WhatsApp_Video_2019-03-30_at_15.04.38_mp4

Comment: Try a better psu.

Comment: @djsmiley2k the OP wrote that he tries already different power supplies.

Comment: @Ingo It does sound like a PSU problem.  The Pi3B+ is not very forgiving of poor charger type power supplies which may be what the questioner is trying.

Comment: What are the voltage and current of all your power supplies?

Comment: Buy the official power supply https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Comment: For further info also see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=237053

Comment: Indeed... without any information on which PSUs have been tried, it doesn't matter if it's one, or one hundred. With the info given, I'd bet on PSU as well.